# get_template_part not working - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using get_template_part('theme-templates/opt_header1') function in header.php and again using get_template_part('carousal') function in opt_header1.php. however,  **get_template_part('theme-templates/opt_header1') function in header.php** is working fine but i want to use another template part inside the **opt_header1.php** which is carousal.php but it is not working.

folder structure is like below...

[folder]

```
     [template-part]

     ... opt_header1.php

     ... carousal.php

     [/template-part]
```

..header.php

[/folder]

using...

```
get_template_part('carousal');
```

please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell get_template_part() the path of the file to add with reference to the theme's root directory.

So you need to do this:

```
get_template_part('theme-templates/carousal');
```

Without telling get_template_part the relative path of the file (carousal.php), the function is looking (*and failing*) for carousal.php in :

1. child-theme/carousal.php
2. parent-theme/carousal.php

Comment: thanks for quick reply. but let me tell you, i want to use **carousal** in **opt_header1.php** both files are on thier root.

Still i need to add "theme-templates/" ?

Comment: Yes you do :)

Please note the theme's root is the theme folder. The 'theme-templates' is a sub-folder. 

The get_template_part function needs to be told about the file to add from the theme's root perspective accordingly -- no matter how deep you are inside sub-folders.